Is there a way to convert QtCore.Qt.Key to a string
I'm capturing keyboard events for a remote desktop application by overriding the keyPressEvent() function like this:
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    key = event.key()
    if key > 9999999999:
        print('key code too long')
        return
    self.io_soc.send(f'key {key}'.encode()

I want to simulate the keyboard event on the other computer, but the problem is that the I need to convert the key code that event.key() gives to a string because pyautogui.press() takes a string as an argument.
I didn't find any way to get the key as a string or convert it. Please provide me with a way to do this conversion, or a way to solve this problem

Use QtGui.QKeySequence(...).toString() with lower() to align more closely with pyautogui's key strings. Additional mappings (PyQt to pyautogui) may need to be added for some keys.
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

MODIFIER_KEYS = {
    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Shift: 'shift',
    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Control: 'ctrl',
    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Alt: 'alt',
    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Meta: 'win',
    # ...
}

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Key Press Example')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()

        # Convert the key code to a string
        key_string = MODIFIER_KEYS.get(key, QtGui.QKeySequence(key).toString().lower())

        print(f'Key pressed: {key_string}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


For a list of key strings supported by pyautogui, refer to the pyautogui keyboard documentation.

